# PayPal-Android-SDK (I am using sandbox, but say: not this device support paypal payments)

Tags: java, paypal, sdk

my problem is that I'm testing in SDK 1.2.0 paypal, I'm from Costa Rica and when I click on the button to buy a thing, I get a message before opening the activity says: not this device support paypal payments and closes the activity.

Comment: Jeff here from PayPal. I'm sorry to hear that you're having problems. Do you have any device logs? Does the sdk work in production? That message shows up for many reasons, including connectivity, server issues, and device rejection. It's on our radar to make it more helpful.